# how to make start up program which starts when os starts

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, c#-4.0

Say i ve a C# program which does something,

I want this program keep running by itself or start executing automatically when the computer starts.

And how can i make this program not detectable i.e., it must not be detected in task manager's process list.

say i ve  a program which displays random number on the windows forms.

```
for(;;)
{
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
}
```

i want this program to run when computer starts and keep on running till the computer shutdowns.
i dont want user to terminate it how to do it.

Comment: *how can i make this program not detectable* You'd be much better off writing your malware in C++. It gets you closer to the operating system's native API do you can more easily do all kinds of shady things!

Comment: Also, hoist that new Random OUT of the for loop.

Comment: The best you can do is create a service. They're just for those kind of stuff, but the program will be detectable. The process will be named `svchost.exe` as with the rest of the services, but you can run `Services.msc` and see it clearly and have the option to shut it down.

Comment: What if i want to replicate the service over other computers.
Say i have that program in my pendrive and when i insert into another PC it must start running in that pc.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to create a `Windows Service`

Have a look here for some more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=VS.80).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/window_service11262005045007AM/window_service.aspx

It is worth noting that Windows will not let you create a service that the user cannot terminate. This is due to security and performance. The only types of services that cannot be stopped, at least to my knowledge, are system drivers.